# regular expression to search only one-digit number

Tags: python, regex, data-science

I'm trying to find sentences having only one digit number along with.

```
sentence="I'm 30 years old."
print(re.match("[0-9]", sentence)
```

then it returns

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='3'>
```

but it's 30 which is two digit number actually, and I don't want it to be matched.
seems like each consisting number 3 and 0 is recognized as one independent number.
And these numbers are two-byte number which is usually used in my country.

How can I change my regular expression?
Thanks!

Comment: Please add an example of what you _want_, and only then an example of what you _do not want_.

Comment: What does "two byte number" even mean here?  I mean, are you trying to match `0-9`, or something else?  Maybe Arabic, Persian, Chinese characters?  Please explain what is happening here.

Comment: Please also add an actual example with the digits used in your country. Do they even match the `\d` pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pattern instead (it looks for single digits):

```
import re
print(re.search(r'\b\d\b', "I'm 30 years old."))
```

Output:

```
None
```

This also works for Unicode characters in Python 3. To also account for punctuation, you can use `\b\d(\b|\.|\?|\!)`

Comment: thanks much for your advice. but i really meant was i wanna find only one-digit so 30 must be coming up with "matched=none"

Comment: @user9191983 Ok, edited. Please make your question more clear next time.

Comment: thanks so much! you actually made me recognize very important stuff when handling this, numbers are two-byte number commonly used in my country...so it might not work properly...

Answer (score 1):

You should add negative lookbehind and negative lookahead to avoid digits before and after a stand-alone digit:

```
re.findall("(?<!\d)\d(?!\d)", "200 20 1 20 200 20 2")
#['1', '2']
re.findall("(?<!\d)\d(?!\d)", "200 20 20 200 20")
#[]
if not re.findall("(?<!\d)\d(?!\d)", "200 20 20 200 20"):
    print("no single-digit numbers")
else:
    print("some single-digit numbers")
```

Comment: thanks so much! you actually made me recognize very important stuff when handling this, numbers are two-byte number commonly used in my country...so it might not work properly...

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `re.search` with the following pattern:

```
(?=.*\d.*\d).*
```

This is a positive lookahead, which will be true if two (or more) digits appear anywhere in the string.  Specifically, we *don't* want this pattern to match, in order to validate your input.

```
sentence="I'm 30 years old."
if not re.search("(?=.*\d.*\d).*", sentence):
    print 'match'
else:
    print 'no match'
```

Comment: thanks much! you got what i wanted. but people use two byte character in my country so it doesn't work...

Comment: Then you have omitted some critical information needed to answer your question.  You should update your question and show us the actual data.

Comment: yeah my apologies and thank you for your advice. I'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little not clear but what I understand is, you want to match only sentences that has only one digit which may be repeated multiple times in the sentences but should not be more than one digit at any particular occurrence. Like,

1. I'm 30 years old. (This should not match as it has 30 which is more than one digit)
2. I'm 3 years old. (This should match as it has 3 which one digit only)
3. I'm 3 years and you are 30 years old. (This should not match as it has 3 and 30 which 30 is a multi digit number)
4. I'm 3 years and you are 5 years old. (This should match because it has 3 and 5 which are only one digit number)
5. I am a good boy. (This does not match because it does not have any digit at all)

Let me know if this is what you want. And if yes, you can use this regex,

```
^(?!.*\d\d)(?=.*\d).*$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` --> Start of string
- `(?!.*\d\d)` --> A negative look ahead which ensures the sentence does not contain any multi digit numbers.
- `(?!.*\d\d)` --> A negative look ahead which ensures the sentence does not contain any multi digit numbers.
- `.*` --> Matches any text
- `$` --> End of string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9tIH5i/1)

Here is sample python code,

```
arr= ["I'm 30 years old.","I'm 3 years old.", "I'm 3 years and you are 30 years old.", "I'm 3 years and you are 5 years old.", "I am a good boy."]

for s in arr:
    if re.search("^(?!.*\d\d)(?=.*\d).*$", s):
        print(s+' --> Sentence has only one digit')
    else:
        print(s+' --> Sentence has either no digit or more than one digit')
```

Which outputs,

```
I'm 30 years old. --> Sentence has either no digit or more than one digit
I'm 3 years old. --> Sentence has only one digit
I'm 3 years and you are 30 years old. --> Sentence has either no digit or more than one digit
I'm 3 years and you are 5 years old. --> Sentence has only one digit
I am a good boy. --> Sentence has either no digit or more than one digit
```